# Accessing variable defined in function

Tags: python, nameerror

```
def myFunc():
    d={}

myFunc()
```

If I try to access the variable d after calling this function, I get "NameError: name 'd' is not defined."

Why is this and what is the proper way to access a variable defined within a function?

Comment: `d` is a local name. Why not *return* it from the function if you need it outside the call?

Comment: @MartijnPieters What I'd like to do is use d in another function, having performed some manipulations on it in myFunc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so myFunc is called in myFunc2 to access d and do other things with it

Comment: I see I can just assign another variable to the function call when return has been assigned. Thank you